# I am getting error while running Modin pandas to speed up my pandas capability.How to resolve this issue?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, modin

```
### Read in the data with Modin
import modin.pandas as pd
s = time.time()
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
e = time.time()
print("Modin Loading Time = {}".format(e-s))
```

**ImportError: Please `pip install modin[ray] or modin[dask] to install an engine**

Comment: Maybe you should try what is described in the error message and install this package?

Comment: 1. That’s not the full error message, is it? 2. Have you tried following what the error message says?

Comment: No i was trying to post it but the stack overflow was giving me errors

Comment: I have posted the image of the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you need to wrap the module in quotes.

To solve:

```
pip install "modin[ray]"
```

or

```
pip install "modin[dask]"
```

It's in the [documentation](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) but not obvious.

Answer (score -1):

As it suggests in the error message, you need to install Modin with either Ray or Dask support.  You might try one of the following:

```
pip install modin[ray]  # if you want to use Modin with Ray
```

or

```
pip install modin[dask]  # if you want to use Modin with Dask
```